# How to get more advanced network interface card type in Linux and Mac OSx

Tags: c, linux, macos, network-programming, network-interface

Using Windows API [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we can get very detailed information about all the network interface cards on the system. Along with all the other useful information, I like to focus on the structure [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s **IfType** field. IF you see then you will find that there are **244** possible values defined in Ipifcons.h and this types are defined by Internet Assigned Names Authority (IANA).

My question is, programmatically, is there ANY way, like Linux API or ioctls, to obtain such specific interface type information using Linux and possibly Mac?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent. The Windows API mixes two properties: protocol and driver.

To get interface protocol (Ethernet, ATM, Loopback, firewire) you can use SIOCGIFHWADDR ioctl which will return "Link Encapsulation". In most computers, it will be either loopback or Ethernet (most devices, including Wifi, tunnels, etc.. are Ethernet). This information is shown by 'ifconfig' tool:

```
$ ifconfig | grep encap
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:cc:xx:xx:xx
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d7:xx:xx:xx
```

To get interface driver, you can explore /sys/class/net/INTERFACE/device/ path. Then you can just use various heuristics:

```
# get driver name
$ readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver
../../../bus/pci/drivers/e1000e
$ readlink /sys/class/net/wlan0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/iwlwifi

# check if it is wifi or not
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/wlan0/wireless/status
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep  2 15:42 /sys/class/net/wlan0/wireless/status
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/eth0/wireless/status
ls: cannot access /sys/class/net/eth0/wireless/status: No such file or directory
```